# How can i show node backend error in react frontend

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, axios

I have different errors in the same API call.
I want to show related errors in the backend to the frontend.
For e.g I want to show **`'Site name exist'`** error in frontend

**Backend:**

```
if (Sname) {
    console.log("Site Name Exist");
    return next(new ErrorResponse("Site name exist", 401));
    
}
 if (Cname) {
    console.log("Company Name Exist");
    return next(new ErrorResponse("Company name exist", 401));
    
}
```

**Frontend**

```
try {
       const { datab } = await axios.post(

          "/api/auth/companyOrigin",
  
        {
            data,
         },
           config  );

      setStep(step + 1);
    }

  catch(error){

        console.log("Error " + error);//Show error here(site name exist)
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

need to manually handle 401 errors

```
axios.post("api/auth/companyOrigin", { data,},config  )
      .catch((error) =>  {
        if (error.response) {
         console.log(error.response.data);
         console.log(error.response.status); 
        }
      })
```

Comment: Is there any way i can show 'site name exist ' in frontend without changing 401

Comment: your backend error should comes under error state and show in here `console.log(error)`. you don't need to change the status since 401 already is an error state

Comment: I know.its showing 40 error but not the msg 'site name exist '

Comment: post the console result

Comment: Error AxiosError: Request failed with status code 401

Comment: try using the `catch` operator. see updated

Comment: console.log(error.response.data.error);
This helped me with your code.
Can you update it so i can mark it correct